# Silicone caulk over latex paneling glue

Tags: caulking

I had glued some paneling to my kitchen walls. The next day I got the silicone caulk and blue tape to finish the job. Looks great! Oops. I never opened the silicone caulk and used the glue in it's place, still looks great, but I want to know if I can put the silicone over the glue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you did with the glue if you went and bought silicone for the same purpose. Where does one caulk paneling? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I used the glue instead of caulking for the finish bead.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can apply silicone over most other adhesives and caulks. It should bond well. Keep in mind that silicone isn't paintable, in case that's your end goal.

Also, applying more caulk of any kind may make your bead more conspicuous, defeating the purpose of doing so (from an aesthetic perspective).